# Multi-boot encrypted operating systems on EFI

Tags: windows-7, linux, encryption, disk-encryption, efi

I'm getting ready to "redo" my desktop computer, encrypting all of my partitions as I install the operating systems.

I currently boot with EFI.

I'm looking to install both Ubuntu 12.04 (really Elementary Luna) and Windows 7 Ultimate, but I'd like both of them to be encrypted.

For Linux, this is pretty simple:

1. EFI partition in FAT-32 mounted at /boot
2. dm-crypt partition for everything else:

   - LVM:

     - swap
     - /

For Windows, it seems that things aren't so simple. Are there any disk-encryption solutions for Windows 7 which will boot in EFI mode and not cause problems with other operating systems? BitLocker seems like an option but my motherboard doesn't have a TPM slot.

What options do I have for installing Linux and Windows alongside each other on the same physical disk, having both of them encrypted with separate keys?